# Python: Removing certain characters from a word using while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given that certain characters are 'abcdef' = *char*
I would like to 1) remove 3rd *char* of the 3 *chars* in a row in a word, and 2) from changed word, remove 2nd *char* of the 2 *chars* in a row in the word.

E.g. If there is a word 'bacifeaghab' it should

1) first remove 'c' and 'a', which is ba(c)ife(a)hab and change word into 'baifehab'

2) remove 'a','e', and 'b', which is b(a)if(e)ha(b) and change word into 'bifha'

This is what I have done so far, but when I run this and put word in it, it doesn't pint anything. Not even error or blank(' '), it just goes to next line without '>>>'.

```
def removal(w):
    x,y = 0,0
    while y < len(w)-2:
        if (w[y] and w[y+1] and w[y+2]) in 'abcdef':
            w = w[:y+2] + w[y+3:]
    while x < len(w):
        if  w[x] in 'abcedf':
            w = w[:x+1] + w[x+2:]
            x = x+1
        else :
            x = x+1
    return(w)
```

Could anyone find out what's wrong??

Since it was first time for me to use while loop, I thought that using double while loop can be a problem, so also tried,

```
def removal(w):
    x,y,z = 0,0,0
    while y < len(w)-2:
        if (w[y] and w[y+1] and w[y+2]) in 'abcdef':
            w = w[:y+2] + w[y+3:]
    return(w)
```

But same result. I also tried print(w) at the end of function. same result.

Comment: Well, I'm python beginner, so I have no idea how to define this 'blank line' correctly. When I press enter key, it just goes to the next line, still empty. when I type anything and press enter, it still goes to the next empty line.

Comment: How are you actually calling these functions?

Comment: Also, it won't print anything because you haven't asked it to. Put some `print(your_value_here)` into the loops and see whether you're entering an infinite loop. `if (w[y] and w[y+1] and w[y+2]) in 'abcdef':` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: It seems you are not printing anything, just defining functions with `def`. If what you posted is all of your code, the `removal` function is not even executed, because you don't call it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You had a couple of mistakes:

There were `2` errors that I have corrected in your code. The first being that you weren't incrementing `x` properly (as you did not need the `elif`) and you had forgotten completely to increment `y`!

I corrected these and then also, in your `if` conditions, your syntax was incorrect. The part in the brackets evaluated to the last element and then just this was checked to see if it was in the string `'abcdef'`. I have corrected that now to check each individual element in turn.

So now the function is:

```
def removal(w):
    chars = 'abcdef'
    x,y = 0,0
    while y < len(w)-2:
        if w[y] in chars and w[y+1] in chars and w[y+2] in chars:
            w = w[:y+2] + w[y+3:]
        y += 3
    while x < len(w):
        if  w[x] in 'abcedf' and w[x+1] in 'abcdef':
            w = w[:x+1] + w[x+2:]
        x += 2
    return w
```

and calling it with `'bacifeahab'` (without the `'g'` which I think was a typo in your e.g.):

```
removal("bacifeahab")
```

`returns` what you wanted:

```
'bifha'
```

Hope this helps!